# A charade: first at the door, second cereal, third wanted, whole united

Tags: riddle

My FIRST is often at the front door;
my SECOND is found in the cereal family;
my THIRD is what most people want;
my WHOLE is one of the united states.

What am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer

> **Matrimony**

My FIRST is often at the front door

> **Mat**

My SECOND is found in the cereal family

> **Rye**

My THIRD is what most people want

> **Money**

My WHOLE is one of the united states

> **Matrimony**

Comment: the WHOLE hint is just too clever

Comment: @user3453281, It sure is!! :D